# What is the point of the alt parameter on submit button?

Tags: html, forms

I was recently looking at some code in a book and in the form for a page they had:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add To Cart" name="submit" alt="Add To Cart" />
```

I understand that the input is there if you use images as buttons. But is there any reason why it is here in this example or are they just covering bases.

Comment: I wonder if a framework or some other approach is auto-adding the `alt` to match the value, without "human" intervention. I can't think of a reason it's useful, but it could, maybe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think they are simply covering bases here.

`alt` is optional for the `input` tag., although it would be needed for accessibility should the `input` be an `img`.

For example: `<input type="image" src="image.jpg" alt="Submit" />.`

In this case, css or some script may be switching out the `value` for an image, or as a I suggested already, the book is simply adding all the attributes you would use if you were coding completely to spec.

Answer (score 2):

As per the w3.org, alt texts are not required unless you use src attribute in tag, so it's not required unless you use src or image.

Answer (score 1):

The *alt* supplies alternate text to be displayed in place of an image but it doesn't make sense with `type="submit"`.

Here's the explanation from the W3C:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_alt.asp

Answer (score 1):

in the manner you have it shown, there is none. if you are using input type="image" then you need to apply the alt attribute the same way you would apply one to an img element.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with the ability to use a src='' for a button image directly on the `<input>` or something like that. It however can only be used with `<input type="image">` so I am not really sure why they used it on the submit button like this. Maybe legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly legacy code.
It's possible this is for accessibility, so that a screen reader can speak the alt tag contents when the mouse is hovering on the form button.
I know accessibility is becoming more and more of a big deal these days in Web coding, so including an alt tag in a form button would support that standard.